# Convert selection to Leading zero format

Tags: excel, vba, leading-zero

I am trying to build a simple macro that converts a selected range with numeric values to a "0000" format (e.g. 50,75,888, 1000  would be 0050,0075, 0888, 1000) i.e. it picks up each value in each cell and and returns a string value back to the sheet which can then be manipulated in Excel

Almost there (I think..) I just need help with the the $format function

```
Sub LeadingZero()
Dim RngSelected As Range
Dim R As String
Dim RCell As Range
Dim Rrng As Range
Dim RevNum As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set RngSelected = Application.InputBox("Please select a range of cells you want to convert to 0000 format", _
                                          "SelectRng", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)

R = RngSelected.Address
Set Rrng = Range(R)

For Each RCell In Rrng.Cells
    RCell.Value = Format$(RCell, "0000")    'this is the line I want to work!
    'RCell.Value2 = Format$(RCell, "0000")  doesn't seem to work either
    Next RCell
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Please tag the question with the programming language you're using

Comment: sorry - excel vba.

Comment: `Rrng.Cells.NumberFormat = "00000"`. Add as many zeros depending upon how big the value of the cell can be.

Comment: Hi shahkalpesh NumberFormat doesn't convert the value to a 4 character string which I can then manipulate. I thought the Format$ cell function did.

Comment: @Chris: Perhaps, what you are looking for is to convert the text to string rather than what appears in the display. For that you can do `range("a1").NumberFormat = "@"` followed by `range("a1").value = format(range("a1").value, "0000")`. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specifically want to do it with formatting? If you actually want to convert the value (useful for lookup and the like) then this function will do what you want.

```
Function FourDigitValues(InputString As String)
Dim X As Long, MyArr As Variant
MyArr = Split(InputString, ",")
For X = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
    MyArr(X) = Right("0000" & MyArr(X), 4)
Next
FourDigitValues = Join(MyArr, ",")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Dan - took a while to figure what this code was doing but got there in the end!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LeadingZero()
Dim RngSelected As Range
Dim R As String
Dim RCell As Range
Dim Rrng As Range
Dim RevNum As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set RngSelected = Application.InputBox("Please select a range of cells you want to convert to 0000 format", _
                                          "SelectRng", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)

R = RngSelected.Address
Set Rrng = Range(R)

For Each RCell In Rrng.Cells
    RCell.NumberFormat = "000#"
Next RCell
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid this looks like it will not return a string which can be manipulated in Excel. I should add I'm testing this out on a Mac and Ive had issues in the past with Mac Excel not doing quite what's expected. My code did seem to work once when I used    'RCell.value = Format$(RCell, "0000") but its not working  now.

Comment: this should return a string:   `For Each RCell In Rrng.Cells
    RCell.NumberFormat = "@"
    If Len(RCell) = 3 Then
        RCell = CStr("0" & RCell)
    ElseIf (Len(RCell) = 2) Then
        RCell = CStr("00" & RCell)
    ElseIf (Len(RCell) = 1) Then
        RCell = CStr("000" & RCell)
    End If
Next RCell`

Comment: Thank you Assaf - after fiddling around with the nested Ifs a bit the code below works perfectly. I'm still mystified why I couldn't get the Format$(RCell, "0000") to work - it produces a string and I don't see I can't then post that back to the same cell once I've converted the cell to text format. The other solutions didn't enter a string back into the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Assaf and Dan Donoghue:

```
Sub LeadingZero2()
'Takes a range with numbers between 1 and 9999 and changes them to text string with "0000" format

Dim RngSelected As Range
Dim RCell As Range
Dim Rrng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set RngSelected = Application.InputBox("Please select a range of cells you want to convert to 0000 format", _
                                          "SelectRng", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)

Set Rrng = Range(RngSelected.Address)

For Each RCell In Rrng.Cells
RCell.NumberFormat = "@"

RCell = CStr(Array("000", "00", "0")(Len(RCell) - 1) & RCell)

Next RCell

End Sub
```

Comment: All of those embedded ifs can be replaced with just 1 line of code `RCell = CStr(Array("000", "00", "0")(Len(RCell) - 1) & RCell)`

Comment: Thanks Dan. Very neat.